# react router v4 history.push() doesn't work when the url changed

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router v4,and I can get "this.props.history".However,"this.props.history.push("/Anli/"+page) " (in the Anli.js,funtion changePage() )doesn't work  when the url in the address bar of the browser has changed.

But “ this.prop.history.push("/home")  ” worked.
I don't know why.

Thanks for help.

index.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import React from 'react';
import Anli from '../views/anli/Anli';

class RouterIndex extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                <Route path="/home" exact component={Home}></Route>

                    <Route path="/AnLi/:page" render={props => <Anli {...props}/>}></Route>
                    <Redirect from="/*" to="/home" />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import RouterIndex from './router';
import reducer from './reducer/reducer';

const store = createStore(reducer);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RouterIndex/>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Anli.js

```
import React from 'react'
import TopNavbar from '../../components/navbar/TopNavbar';
import SuspendBar from '../../components/suspendBar/SuspendBar';
import ajaxhost from '../../ajaxhost';
import SubCards from '../../components/subPageCard/SubCards';
import {Pagination} from "antd";
import { withRouter,Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./anli.css"
import Footer_ from '../../components/footer/Footer_';



class Anli extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      datas: [],
      pages:{}
    }
    this.changePage = this.changePage.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let page = this.props.match.params.page;
    let url_;
    if (page === 1) {
      url_ = this.state.url
    }else{
      url_ = this.state.url + suffix + page
    }
    let url = encodeURIComponent(url_).replace(new RegExp("%", "g"), '~');
    let that = this;
    fetch(ajaxhost +'/search/hunlicehua/'+ url, {
      method: 'GET'
    }).then((res) => {
      if (res.ok) {
        res.json().then(function (result) {
          debug && console.log(result);
          that.setState({
            datas:result.datas,
            pages:result.pages
          })
        })
      }
    }).catch((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    })
  }

  changePage(page){

    console.log(this.props.history);
    this.props.history.push("/AnLi/"+ page);

  }
  render() {
    const {datas,pages} = this.state;

    const current = parseInt(this.props.match.params.page);
    const total = parseInt(pages.list[pages.list.length - 1].num);
    return (
      <div history={this.props.history}>
       <TopNavbar/>
       <SuspendBar/>

       <SubCards datas={datas}/>
       <div className="pagination-custom" >
          <Pagination defaultCurrent={current} total={total} onChange={this.changePage}/>
       </div>

      <Footer_ />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: do you get any error ? you url gets updated ?

Comment: No error,the url in the address bar gets updated,but the page content not

Comment: Can you share it over coesandbox or github ?

Answer (score 0):

**First Try:**

inside of :

```
changePage(page){
  console.log(this.props.history);
  this.props.history.push("/AnLi/"+ page);
}
```

make sure you are passing in a string (as the parameter) and not an integer , and then combining the string together, or you could just run `page.toString()`

**second try:**

Instead of abstracting out an onClick event and running history.push, can you use react-routers `Link` Component for the button?

```
            <Link to={`/topics/${id}`}>{name}</Link>
```

check out this most recent article on react-router.

https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-nested-routes/

Whenever I implement route changes in my projects I always use `Link` Component, you can pass changing and dynamic routes directly into the `to` prop of the `Link` Component.

Comment: It doesn't work either. I just do like this.                    `<Redirect from="/AnLi/page/:page" to="/AnLi/:page"exact component={Anli}></Redirect>` And in the function: `let k = "/AnLi/page" + page.toString();

    this.props.history.push(k);`

Comment: I don't think it's a good way.But I don't know what else I can do.